# Insufficient permissions to list objects for bucket "XXXX" while deleting AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I got accidentally locked out of the AWS S3 bucket by not meeting certain conditions. I accidentally set bucket policies that explicitly deny access to any requests outside the allowed IP addresses. Now I am not able to either list objects, view the permissions, or anything inside the bucket and completely locked out of it.

How can I regain access to the bucket?

Here are some of the error screenshots:

Insufficient Permissions to list oBjects for a bucket while trying to delete the bucket

[image: Insufficient Permissions to list oBjects for a bucket while trying to delete the bucket]

**Objects Page**
[image: Insufficient permissions to list objects]

**Permission Page**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as a **root user** as explained in the following AWS docs:

- [I accidentally denied everyone access to my Amazon S3 bucket. How do I regain access?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-accidentally-denied-access/)

Comment: Logging through the Root user worked. Thanks, @Marcin

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was fixed after adding `s3:List*` to a policy of the user.

```json
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:List*"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
}
```